# Python OpenCV segmentation fault when setting region of interest

Tags: python, opencv, rectangles, bounding-box, roi

I have a python script that contains a class which creates a interactive draggable and movable bounding box. I want to use this to create a region of interest.

I am attempting to run this on a video file. To draw the rectangle, the left mouse button is used and then released to finish drawing. During this, the frame is freezed. To confirm the box, double clicking with left button is implemented. When I do this, my program crashes with seg fault.

I don't know how I can debug this and I suspect this is some version issue?

I am running OpenCV 4.5.5

My code for the region box selector is below:

```
import cv2


class Rect:
    x = None
    y = None
    w = None
    h = None

    def printit(self):
        print(str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ',' + str(self.w) + ',' + str(self.h))


class DragRectangle:
    keepWithin = Rect()
    # To store rectangle
    outRect = Rect()
    anchor = Rect()
    sBlk = 4
    initialized = False

    image = None

    wname = ""

    returnflag = False


    active = False
    drag = False
    TL = False
    TM = False
    TR = False
    LM = False
    RM = False
    BL = False
    BM = False
    BR = False
    hold = False

    def __init__(self, Img, windowName, windowWidth, windowHeight):
        self.image = Img

        self.wname = windowName

        self.keepWithin.x = 0
        self.keepWithin.y = 0
        self.keepWithin.w = windowWidth
        self.keepWithin.h = windowHeight

        self.outRect.x = 0
        self.outRect.y = 0
        self.outRect.w = 0
        self.outRect.h = 0


def dragrect(event, x, y, flags, dragObj):
    if x < dragObj.keepWithin.x:
        x = dragObj.keepWithin.x
    if y < dragObj.keepWithin.y:
        y = dragObj.keepWithin.y
    if x > (dragObj.keepWithin.x + dragObj.keepWithin.w - 1):
        x = dragObj.keepWithin.x + dragObj.keepWithin.w - 1
    if y > (dragObj.keepWithin.y + dragObj.keepWithin.h - 1):
        y = dragObj.keepWithin.y + dragObj.keepWithin.h - 1

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        mouseDown(x, y, dragObj)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        mouseUp(dragObj)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        mouseMove(x, y, dragObj)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        mouseDoubleClick(x, y, dragObj)


def pointInRect(pX, pY, rX, rY, rW, rH):
    if rX <= pX <= (rX + rW) and rY <= pY <= (rY + rH):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def mouseDoubleClick(eX, eY, dragObj):
    if dragObj.active:
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x, dragObj.outRect.y, dragObj.outRect.w, dragObj.outRect.h):
            dragObj.returnflag = True
            cv2.destroyWindow(dragObj.wname)


def mouseDown(eX, eY, dragObj):
    if dragObj.active:
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.TL = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.TR = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.BL = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.BR = True
            return

        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w / 2 - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.TM = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w / 2 - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.BM = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h / 2 - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.LM = True
            return
        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h / 2 - dragObj.sBlk,
                       dragObj.sBlk * 2, dragObj.sBlk * 2):
            dragObj.RM = True
            return

        if pointInRect(eX, eY, dragObj.outRect.x, dragObj.outRect.y, dragObj.outRect.w, dragObj.outRect.h):
            dragObj.anchor.x = eX - dragObj.outRect.x
            dragObj.anchor.w = dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.anchor.x
            dragObj.anchor.y = eY - dragObj.outRect.y
            dragObj.anchor.h = dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.anchor.y
            dragObj.hold = True

            return

    else:
        dragObj.outRect.x = eX
        dragObj.outRect.y = eY
        dragObj.drag = True
        dragObj.active = True
        return


def mouseMove(eX, eY, dragObj):
    if dragObj.drag & dragObj.active:
        dragObj.outRect.w = eX - dragObj.outRect.x
        dragObj.outRect.h = eY - dragObj.outRect.y
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return

    if dragObj.hold:
        dragObj.outRect.x = eX - dragObj.anchor.x
        dragObj.outRect.y = eY - dragObj.anchor.y

        if dragObj.outRect.x < dragObj.keepWithin.x:
            dragObj.outRect.x = dragObj.keepWithin.x
        if dragObj.outRect.y < dragObj.keepWithin.y:
            dragObj.outRect.y = dragObj.keepWithin.y
        if (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w) > (dragObj.keepWithin.x + dragObj.keepWithin.w - 1):
            dragObj.outRect.x = dragObj.keepWithin.x + dragObj.keepWithin.w - 1 - dragObj.outRect.w
        if (dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h) > (dragObj.keepWithin.y + dragObj.keepWithin.h - 1):
            dragObj.outRect.y = dragObj.keepWithin.y + dragObj.keepWithin.h - 1 - dragObj.outRect.h

        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return

    if dragObj.TL:
        dragObj.outRect.w = (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w) - eX
        dragObj.outRect.h = (dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h) - eY
        dragObj.outRect.x = eX
        dragObj.outRect.y = eY
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.BR:
        dragObj.outRect.w = eX - dragObj.outRect.x
        dragObj.outRect.h = eY - dragObj.outRect.y
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.TR:
        dragObj.outRect.h = (dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h) - eY
        dragObj.outRect.y = eY
        dragObj.outRect.w = eX - dragObj.outRect.x
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.BL:
        dragObj.outRect.w = (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w) - eX
        dragObj.outRect.x = eX
        dragObj.outRect.h = eY - dragObj.outRect.y
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return

    if dragObj.TM:
        dragObj.outRect.h = (dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h) - eY
        dragObj.outRect.y = eY
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.BM:
        dragObj.outRect.h = eY - dragObj.outRect.y
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.LM:
        dragObj.outRect.w = (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w) - eX
        dragObj.outRect.x = eX
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return
    if dragObj.RM:
        dragObj.outRect.w = eX - dragObj.outRect.x
        clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)
        return


def mouseUp(dragObj):
    dragObj.drag = False
    disableResizeButtons(dragObj)
    straightenUpRect(dragObj)
    if dragObj.outRect.w == 0 or dragObj.outRect.h == 0:
        dragObj.active = False

    clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj)


def disableResizeButtons(dragObj):
    dragObj.TL = dragObj.TM = dragObj.TR = False
    dragObj.LM = dragObj.RM = False
    dragObj.BL = dragObj.BM = dragObj.BR = False
    dragObj.hold = False


def straightenUpRect(dragObj):
    """
    Make sure x, y, w, h of the Rect are positive
    """
    if dragObj.outRect.w < 0:
        dragObj.outRect.x = dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w
        dragObj.outRect.w = -dragObj.outRect.w
    if dragObj.outRect.h < 0:
        dragObj.outRect.y = dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h
        dragObj.outRect.h = -dragObj.outRect.h


def clearCanvasNDraw(dragObj):
    # Draw
    tmp = dragObj.image.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(tmp, (dragObj.outRect.x, dragObj.outRect.y),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    drawSelectMarkers(tmp, dragObj)
    cv2.imshow(dragObj.wname, tmp)
    cv2.waitKey()


def drawSelectMarkers(image, dragObj):
    """
    Draw markers on the dragged rectangle
    """
    # Top-Left
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Top-Rigth
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Bottom-Left
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Bottom-Right
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)

    # Top-Mid
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x + int(dragObj.outRect.w / 2) - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + int(dragObj.outRect.w / 2) - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Bottom-Mid
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x + int(dragObj.outRect.w / 2) - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + int(dragObj.outRect.w / 2) - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + dragObj.outRect.h - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Left-Mid
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y + int(dragObj.outRect.h / 2) - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + int(dragObj.outRect.h / 2) - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
    # Right-Mid
    cv2.rectangle(image, (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk,
                          dragObj.outRect.y + int(dragObj.outRect.h / 2) - dragObj.sBlk),
                  (dragObj.outRect.x + dragObj.outRect.w - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2,
                   dragObj.outRect.y + int(dragObj.outRect.h / 2) - dragObj.sBlk + dragObj.sBlk * 2),
                  (255,0 , 0), 2)
```

This is my inference:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
 
 
# capture frames from a camera
sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 9)
import regionselector
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Blcak-fila.avi')
wName = "Original"
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)





while(1):
 
    # reads frames from a camera
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    rectI = regionselector.DragRectangle(frame, wName, width, height)
    cv2.namedWindow(rectI.wname)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(rectI.wname, regionselector.dragrect, rectI)


    
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(5,5),0)
    


    # converting BGR to HSV 239237 2952
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
     
    # define range of red color in HSV
    lower_red = np.array([30,150,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])
     
    # create a red HSV colour boundary and
    # threshold HSV image
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(blur,blur, mask= mask)
 
    # Display an original image
    cv2.imshow(wName,frame)

    
 
    

 
    # Wait for Esc key to stop
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
 
 
# Close the window
cap.release()
 
# De-allocate any associated memory usage
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After some digging around I found out the existence of a built in module called `faulthandler` that can give a tracedump of the seg fault.

This can be enabled in Python using:

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
```

You can also enable it CLI/shell.

It gave me this dump:

```
File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 227 in mouseUp
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 70 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 227 in mouseUp
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 70 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 156 in mouseMove
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 72 in dragrect
  File "/home/user/Desktop/tests/regionselector.py", line 257 in clearCanvasNDraw
```

I am running on ArchLinux. I tried running this on OpenCV 3.4 in conda environment and got the same result.

I tried on my Mac machine and weirdly, I didn't get a segmentation fault. The window closed but it didnt return any coordinates or error message. I have not yet tested on a Windows machine.

Going further, I debugged with gdb and got this stacktrace:

```
Thread 1 "python" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff0c772aa in QtOpenCVPython::QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QtOpenCVPython::QMouseEvent*) () from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5Widgets-e69d94fb.so.5.15.0
```